# text is seen after masking on hovering the mask position when using pymupdf

Tags: pymupdf

Am masking email id in PDF using pymupdf. When i open the file there is no hyperlink seen under mail id but when the text is extracted hyperlink is seen.Due to that after when i mask mail id and hover on that masking am able to see the mail id.Had tried different methods but none were working.Any suggestion on this scenario!

Had tried links and annots methods but none were useful

Comment: What does that mean: "masking email"? And what were the "different" methods you tried? The question is too unclear to be answered.

Comment: @KJ yes, that was my suspicion too, but what other "different" methods might that be? As yu write, a redaction would remove the text and the link altogether.